Is there any information on when Apple plans to extend its 2023 Live Voicemail feature beyond the US?
As an Australian User - I was quite excited by the announcement of Live Voicemail at WWDC 2023 for its release in iOS 17 in September 2023.
Then I found out that it hadn't been released beyond the US.

Live Voicemail is available only in English in the United States and Canada, excluding Guam, Puerto Rico and the U.S. Virgin Islands.

My question is: Is there any information on when Apple plans to extend its 2023 Live Voicemail feature beyond the US?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
